# Kendo UI Grid - Filtering with multiple items causes error

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I've a Kendo UI grid and I'm trying to apply filtering.

The following filter clause works fine:

```
filter: [{
   logic: "or",
   filters: [
           {
               field: "country",
               value: "France",
               operator: "eq"
           },
           {
               field: "country",
               value: "Germany",
               operator: "eq"
           }
        ]
```

}

However when I add a 3rd filter is fails with an error "cannot call method set of undefined".

The filter with 3 items is:

```
filter: [{
   logic: "or",
   filters: [
           {
               field: "country",
               value: "France",
               operator: "eq"
           },
           {
               field: "country",
               value: "Germany",
               operator: "eq"
           },
           {
               field: "country",
               value: "UK",
               operator: "eq"
           }
        ]
   }
```

I'm really stumped by this as I expected I could add any number of filter items

Comment: Is it a typo error or do you really have `filters` as the name of the first `array`? The first should be `filter` (singular) while the second `filters` (plural). Other than that it works fine for me (Kendo UI - v2012.3.1114)

Comment: That was just a typo on entering my query. I've corrected my syntax. filter is the property of the Kendo UI Datasource

Comment: Do you mean that still doesn't work? Which version are you using? Can you show how are you using it?

Comment: It's still not working, it's difficult to demonstrate as I'm using server mode.  If I change the third filter to be on a different field then it also works (e.g - City eq London). I'm wondering if there is a limitation in the number of equals on the same column. when you dropdown the filter on a column you can only put 2 entries in there. I'm using v2012.2.710

Answer (score 0):

Issue was down to the version of the Kendo controls, once I grabbed the latest version the issue was gone